# Show that, if $S $ is contractable, then any closed curve is homotopic to a constant curve

Tags: complex-analysis

> We say that a topological set $S$ is $contractable$ if there exists $s_{0}$ in $S$ and a continous map $K: S\times[0,1]\rightarrow S$ such that for all  $s $ in  $S$ we have  $K(s,0) = s$ and  $K(s,1)= s_{0}$

1.Show that, if  $S $ is contractable, then S is simply connected.

Now I found the definition we use in our class for simply connected, which is as follows:

> An open subset U ⊆ C is called simply connected if it is path-connected
>   and if any closed curve is homotopic to a constant curve.

I was able to prove path connectedness, however, seem to be stuck in proving the second part.
Some help on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\gamma:[0,1]\to S$ is a loop based at $x_0$, then $K(\gamma{t_1},t_2):[0,1]^2\to S$ is a homotopy from $\gamma(t_1)=K(\gamma(t_1),0)$ to the constant curve at $s_0=K(\gamma(t_1),1)$.

Comment: Ahhh yes that makes sense :) thank's alot

Comment: This is not a homotopy based at $s_0$, since $K(s_0,t)$ might be $\neq s_0$ as $t$ moves along $[0,1]$. But using the path described by $K(s_0,t)$ you can concatenate this path with the homotopy to get one that it is.